# Increase Size of Black Bullets in Image in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

Given the following image:

[image]

I need to output this image:

[image]

I want to increase the size of Black Pixels in the image using C# or AForge.Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image processing operation you need is *[morphological](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/morphology_filters.html) [dilation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/88f713d4-a469-30d2-dc57-5ceb33210723.htm)* or, in your case with black dots on white background *[morphological erosion](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/90a69d73-0e5a-3e27-cc52-5864f542b53e.htm)*.

Comment: @OP Specifically this example would need erosion (erosion expands dark areas, dilation expands light areas)

Comment: Indeed. We are eroding the white region.

Comment: Thank you, i used Erosion filter and it did what i need